# Converting raw Accelerometer values to 12 bit number

Tags: c, byte, microcontroller, accelerometer, bit-shift

I am coding an Accelerometer that is in built in one of the microcontroller (TZ1000 series). I am trying send the data BLE to PC application. I have to send the number in 2 bytes and receive it in application side and combine it to form a 12-bit number. I am facing problem in converting the actual raw accelerometer values to 12 bit number. I am reading it in following format.

```
acc->ReadAcceleration((uint16_t*)buf);  
ChannelX[M] = (buf[0].acceleration << 4) & 0xFFF0;
ChannelY[M] = (buf[1].acceleration << 4) & 0xFFF0;
ChannelZ[M] = (buf[2].acceleration << 4) & 0xFFF0;
```

Where the variables are of type and size as follows,

```
int16_t ChannelX[4] = {0,0,0,0};
int16_t ChannelY[4] = {0,0,0,0};
int16_t ChannelZ[4] = {0,0,0,0};
```

`buf` is of type `static ACCEL_ACCELERATION buf[12];` and the structure of it is as follows,

```
  typedef struct _ACCEL_ACCELERATION {
       uint16_t updated      : 1;
      uint16_t reserved     : 3;
      int16_t  acceleration :12;
    } ACCEL_ACCELERATION;
```

Now when i am converting this data to two bytes and transmit over BLE, I am following below logic.

```
uart_tx_data[i]   = (uint8_t) (ChannelX[j] & 0xFF);
uart_tx_data[i+1] = (uint8_t) ((ChannelX[j]>>12) & 0x0F) ;

uart_tx_data[i+2] = (uint8_t) (ChannelY[j] & 0xFF);
uart_tx_data[i+3] = (uint8_t) ((ChannelY[j]>>12) & 0x0F) ;

uart_tx_data[i+4] = (uint8_t) (ChannelZ[j] & 0xFF);
uart_tx_data[i+5] = (uint8_t) ((ChannelZ[j]>>12) & 0x0F) ;
```

where variable is of type`static uint8_t uart_tx_data[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};`

At receive side i am converting it to a 12 bit number as follows,

```
X[i]= (num[2] & 0xFF) | ((num[3] & 0x0F) << 12);
```

where `int[] X= new int[2];`

The values that I am getting is wrong, I checked it by doing 1g test on the accelerometer. For example when its flat it should give a number closer to zero. and at 1g it should give a number according to the sensitivity I have set ( in my case its 8G and value  is 256).

Is there anything wrong in the logic I have used?? I request some one to help me on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure how much this may help, but you might want to make sure the value is being sent and received with the same endianness.

Comment: Say the number inside the buffer `uart_tx_data[2] = 0x20` and `uart_tx_data[3]=0x01`. My desired output should be `X[i]=0x0120` which is a 12 bit number.

Comment: Your shifts don’t seem rational. You’re sending the lowest eight bits and highest four, while you’re shifting everything so lowest four are empty. To me that seems you’re missing four bits of the result and lowest four are always zero anyway.

Comment: there's a lot of byte shuffling going on here, I'm having trouble following it,, that would be my first guess as the problem. Any way you can print out and see what you've got at each step (raw data from the accelerometer, data in the channels, data in `uart_tx_data`)? Also, unless you're _sure_ that bitfield is operating correctly, read up on those. There are some "gotchas" associated with bitfields, that I think boil down to they're implementation-defined. They produce elegant-looking code, but I believe shifting and bitmasking is more robust.

Comment: @yano I corrected it, that should have been 8 bit right shift instead of 12bit in `uart_tx_data` buffer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shifts are all off. Use a constant to see what’s happening. Example: put 0x1234 into the structure (note I’m assuming 16bit variable and not caring about the bit fields in the structure which change things a bit but not the reason why it’s not working)

```
ChannelX[M] = (buf[0].acceleration << 4) & 0xFFF0;
```

This will result in 0x2340. Not sure why you want the lowest four bits zero but let’s go with it. Then you send it:

```
uart_tx_data[i]   = (uint8_t) (ChannelX[j] & 0xFF);
uart_tx_data[i+1] = (uint8_t) ((ChannelX[j]>>12) & 0x0F) ;
```

First part will be `0x2340 & 0xff == 0x40` so you’re always sending four zeroes from the lowest bits. Second part will be `0x2340 >> 12 == 0x02` so you’re missing the whole 3 part there.

Why not simply take the value of `acceleration` and send it without making four lowest bits zero? The bit fields will make it into a 12bit value already. And when sending shift by 8, not 12.

```
ChannelX[M] = buf[0].acceleration;
uart_tx_data[i]   = (uint8_t) (ChannelX[j] & 0xFF);
uart_tx_data[i+1] = (uint8_t) ((ChannelX[j]>>8) & 0x0F);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I corrected it from 12 to 8 and it is sending the proper values. Any ideas towards the receive side `X[i]= (num[2] & 0xFF) | ((num[3] & 0x0F) << 8);` Say instead of getting a value 256, I am getting a value of 128. I am using Processing IDE on the receiver side.